# Failing to load project through Reflection

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, reflection, system.data.sqlite

I'm trying to load a `WpfCustomControlLibrary` at runtime with `Reflection` but it throws a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` when it has to access `System.Data.SQLite`.

The idea of the current setup is that the running application isn't aware of the exact control it has to load, as long as it matches a specific `Interface`.

At this point i'm trying to load the project directly from the Debug folder of the `WpfCustomControlLibrary` to be sure all referenced libraries exist in the same directory as the project itself.

This is how I currently try to load the control:

```
UserControl myControl = null;
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"SomePath\bin\Debug\ControlLibrary.dll");

Type[] types = null;
try
{
    types = asm.GetTypes();

    if (types != null)
    {
        foreach (var t in types.Where(t => t != null))
        {
            if (t.Name == "MyControl")
            {
                myControl = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as UserControl;

                Type[] ifs = t.GetInterfaces();

                var project = ifs.FirstOrDefault(x => x == typeof(IMyInterface));

                if(project != null)
                {
                    IMyInterface actualProject = myControl as IMyInterface;

                    //Creates a new database when none exists.
                    actualProject.Init(@"Data Source=.\Database.db;Version=3;"); //<-- It fails on this line
                    actualProject.Start();
                }

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"Failed to load Project: {ex}");
}
```

When I load `MyControl` as a referenced project, it doesn't have any problems accessing `System.Data.SQLite`.

the `actualProject.Init` method basically runs this code:

```
// Create database if it doesn't exist yet
foreach (string sub in this.ConnectionString.Split(';'))
{
    string prefix = "Data Source=";
    if (sub.Contains(prefix))
    {
        string name = sub.Remove(0, prefix.Length);

        if (!File.Exists(name))
        {
            SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(name);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Edit: added stacktrace. Unfortunately my work PC isn't in english so I had to translate some bits.

Stacktrace:

> at Database.DbConnection.CreateDatabaseIfNeeded()
> at Database.DbConnection..ctor(String ConnectionString) in \usercontrol project path\DbConnection.cs:line 32
> at  ControlLibrary.connectors.Database..ctor(String ConnectionString) in \usercontrol project path\connectors\Database.cs:line 43
> at ControlLibrary.UserControl1.Init(String DatabaseConnectionString) in \usercontrol project path\UserControl1.xaml.cs:line 779
> at DynamicProjectLoaderTest.MainWindow.BtnLoad1_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in \main project path\DynamicProjectLoaderTest\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 56

It looks like it's not searching the right directory for the System.Data.SQLite.dll as the file is actually in either in:

usercontrol project path\bin\Debug\x64 or

usercontrol project path\bin\Debug\x86.

FusionLog:

> === Status information before binding ===
> LOG: DisplayName = System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.112.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139
> (Fully-specified)
> LOG: Appbase = file:///main project path/DynamicProjectLoaderTest/bin/Debug/
> LOG: originally PrivatePath = NULL
> Calling assembly : Database, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
> ===

> LOG: this binding starts in LoadFrom load context.
> WRSCH: native image is not searched in LoadFrom context. Native image is only searched in default load context, such as Assembly.Load ().
> LOG: application configuration file used: main project path\bin\Debug\DynamicProjectLoaderTest.exe.Config
> LOG: host configuration file is used:
> LOG: computer configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config wordt gebruikt.
> LOG: referral after policy: System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.112.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139
> LOG: an attempt is made to download URL file:///main project path/bin/Debug/**System.Data.SQLite.DLL**.
> LOG: an attempt is made to download URL file:///main project path/bin/Debug/**System.Data.SQLite**/System.Data.SQLite.DLL.
> LOG: an attempt is made to download URL file:///main project path/bin/Debug/System.Data.SQLite.EXE.
> LOG: an attempt is made to download URL file:///main project path/bin/Debug/**System.Data.SQLite**/System.Data.SQLite.EXE.
> LOG: an attempt is made to download URL file:///control project path/bin/Debug/**System.Data.SQLite.DLL**.
> WRSCH: comparing the assembly name showed that the following does not match: revision number
> LOG: an attempt is made to download file:///control project path/bin/Debug/**System.Data.SQLite**/System.Data.SQLite.DLL.
> LOG: an attempt is made to download file:///control project path/bin/Debug/**System.Data.SQLite.EXE** te downloaden.
> LOG: an attempt is made to download URL file:///control project path/bin/Debug/**System.Data.SQLite**/System.Data.SQLite.EXE.

Comment: You realise if you distribute your app and install to program files, the user will not be able to write to files in that folder's tree at run time? Your database needs to go somewhere else like appdata.

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace? While Andy is correct, this should lead to a different exception. And both need fixing.

Comment: What's the code it falls over on, and specifically which line? Also. You realise MEF exists?

Comment: It fails on `actualProject.Init(@"Data Source=.\Database.db;Version=3;");`, I'll add the stacktrace to the question

Comment: @Andy, The location of the database file, once the application is deployed, will in a suitable directory. Right now it's just there for testing.

Comment: You need the sqllite dll alongside the entry point exe. When you run an exe, everything is running in it's context. If you were to reference a project, you'd see it's dll and anything it references end up in the debug folder for the exe.

Comment: From what I understand is that when I load a project with reflection it still runs from the directory of the entry point. all the required libraries are in this directory as the control works fine when I run it as a reference.